CS-Cart 4.18.2 2FA on my registration page with email
I have a simple website on my local pc.
That is built with cs-cart 4.18.2.
And I am going to add 2FA to my registration page.
If anyone knows how to do it, please help me.
I tried to use OTP for that but I don't have strong knowledge about CS-Cart so I asked to the AI Chat and follow the steps he told me.
But it doesn't work at all.
As I guess, we can use sendgrid.
So I just asked to the AI Chat he provided me with the sample code.
But it wasn't clear and I can't be sure to embed the codes.
Furthermore, it doesn't work well.
Actually, at all.
